# Alertmanager `inhibit_rules` not working?

Tags: devops, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to configure something that seems very simple:
"If the datasource (prometheus) is down, don't spam alerts, and only notify that Prometheus is down"

Immediately I went to `inhibit_rules`, and after trying probably several hundred combinations I cannot make it work under any condition.

This is my config:

```
inhibit_rules:
  - source_matchers:
      - 'alertname = prometheus-up'
    target_matchers:
      - 'datasource = prometheus'
    equal:
      - 'datasource'
```

Now I've honestly tried any label combination I can think of, used different labels, no labels, no `equal`, NOTHING works, all alerts are fires whenever the datasource is down.

What am I missing here? the Prometheus/Alertmanager docs are terrible and provide no help, and no examples exist expect very simple use cases.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles upon this as I would assume Alex got it working after 9 months. His example should work in the current alertmanager versions setup like this:

```
inhibit_rules:
  - source_matchers: [alertname="prometheus-up"]
    target_matchers: [datasource="prometheus"]
    equal: ['datasource']
```

For some logical context, if the alert "prometheus-up" is firing any alert that has the datasource label "prometheus" should then not fire alerts assuming the datasource label is equal to whatever the datasource label is of the firing "prometheus-up" alert.

Comment: it's the same thing, isn't it? What's the difference?

Comment: @MykytaOrlov While you would suspect it is the same I have ran into countless issues all due to formatting.  I found this current listed setup gets it working as expected.